# How to get number of tests run by Nose?

Tags: python-2.7, nose

Nose is kicked off programatically:

```
test_argv = ['nosetests', '-a', 'level=gold', '--with-id']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = nose.run(argv=test_argv)
```

For reporting purposes, I would like to record **how many tests** were run by nose.

Nose's console output has how many tests were run.

```
------------------------------------
Ran 294 in x.x seconds
```

Any ideas of how I can access that number?

(Unfortunately, `result` is a bool, so it's not helpful...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run `--with-xunit` [plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html) to generate xml file and read number of test from it

Answer (score 0):

nosetests --collect-only can give count of test cases.

Comment: --collect-only outputs a number to the console that your eyes can read, but how to read that number programatically?  That's the question

Comment: in program you can run this command using subprocess like this 

count = subprocess.call("nostests --collect-only")

Comment: That always returns count=1.  Not helpful.

Comment: can you try this one?

`import re`

`res = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d+",commands.getstatusoutput('nosetests --collect-only /path/to/testscripts/')[1])[0]
`

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`  If I remove the `[0]` at the end of the `re.findall` function, I get an empty list.